# React Router v6 child route not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

With React Router v6 I want to render the callback page. Although I'm not able to get the output from the element prop in my screen. I'm only getting the output from out and always a blank screen or a 404 for the callback page. What am I missing with the new React Router?

```js
const App: React.FC = () => (
  <>
    <GlobalStyle />
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading fullScreen />}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute component={Home} />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<PublicRoute component={Login} />} />
        <Route path="/auth/*" element={<p>auth</p>}>
          <Route path="callback" element={<p>callback</p>} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  </>
);
```

```js
const App: React.FC = () => (
  <>
    <GlobalStyle />
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading fullScreen />}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute component={Home} />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<PublicRoute component={Login} />} />
        <Route path="/auth/callback" element={<p>callback</p>} />
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  </>
);
```

Also using an `Outlet` doesn't seem to solve the problem..

```js
const App: React.FC = () => (
  <>
    <GlobalStyle />
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading fullScreen />}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute component={Home} />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<PublicRoute component={Login} />} />
        <Route path="/auth/*" element={<><p>auth</p><Outlet /></>}>
          <Route path="callback" element={<p>callback</p>} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  </>
);
```

The `BrowserRouter` is in my `Root` component, which is rendering `App`.

As expected output I do not **need** the `auth` route itself the show anything (like with an `<Outlet />`, although I did try it), but instead I only want the child route to display.

Comment: Just to debug, using `<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />` have you the same outcome?

Comment: Yes, with and without the Private/Public routes. `Home` and `Login` to work fine :)

Comment: Additionally, here an example for nested routes https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#configuring-routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't strictly relate to your example (since you're using an exact path in the child route) but I ran into a similar issue and figure it may be related. I solved it by adding the `index` property to the child route. [According to the docs for Outlets:](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet)

> If the parent route matched exactly, it will render a child index route or nothing if there is no index route.

Using your final example, something like this should work if your use case is similar:

```
 const App: React.FC = () => (
  <>
    <GlobalStyle />
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading fullScreen />}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute component={Home} />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<PublicRoute component={Login} />} />
        <Route path="/auth/callback" element={<><p>auth</p><Outlet /></>}>
          <Route index element={<p>callback</p>} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  </>
);
```

(Note this only meant to be demonstrative, since the use of the Outlet and child Route are unnecessary in this simplistic example)

Answer (score 4):

You need to render an `Outlet` for nested routes to be rendered into.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Route
  path="/auth/*"
  element={(
    <>
      <p>auth</p>
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes rendered out here
    </>
  )}
>
  <Route path="callback" element={<p>callback</p>} />
</Route>
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-child-route-not-rendering]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer since I've already tried that as well. Also an `Outlet` doesn't show the child page.

Comment: @ronnyrr Seems to render without issue for me, check the linked codesandbox. If you're still having an issue perhaps there's something else going on in your code. Could you try creating a codesandbox of your own that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?